# Is regex in python different with regex in other system like PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, regex, postgresql

I have this code to parsing street and house number in Python

```
import re 

def parse_street(address):
    pattern = r'^(.*?)(?i)\b no\b'
    match = re.match(pattern, address)
    if match:
        return match.group(1).strip()
    else:
        return None


def parse_housenumber(address):
    pattern = r'(?i)\bno\.?\s*([\dA-Z]+)'
    match = re.search(pattern, address)
    print(match)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return None

df['street'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(parse_street(x)))
df['house_number'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(parse_housenumber(x)))
```

Why I am getting error for running the query in postgresql with the same regex syntax query like:

```sql
SELECT (regexp_matches('Jl. ABC No.01', '^(.*?)(?i)\b no\b'))[1]
```

The error message is:
`ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`

Is regex in python different with regex in other system? How can I convert my python function to PostgreSQL syntax? I want to add "street" and "house_number" column from "address" column within the same table

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are receiving?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is about invalid regular expression, I have edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, most regex engines' syntax is different, to a lesser or greater degree. This is why the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag requires another tag specifying the engine, tool or a programming language to which the regex question pertains.

From [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX) (emphasis mine):

> An ARE can **begin** with *embedded options*: a sequence `(?xyz)` (where `xyz` is one or more alphabetic characters) specifies options affecting the rest of the RE. These options override any previously determined options — in particular, they can override the case-sensitivity behavior implied by a regex operator, or the `flags` parameter to a regex function. The available option letters are shown in Table 9.24. Note that these same option letters are used in the `flags` parameters of regex functions.

Thus, this regex is not legal in PostgreSQL:

```
^(.*?)(?i)\b no\b
```

But, this one is:

```
(?i)^(.*?)\b no\b
```

However, while legal, it still doesn't mean the same as the Python one, because the meaning of `\b` is different: for Python, it is a word boundary assertion; for PostgreSQL, it is a backspace character. The word boundary assertion is `\y`, and you can also be more precise with `\m` and `\M` (word start and end assertions, respectively). Thus, the equivalent PostgreSQL regular expression is:

```
(?i)^(.*?)\y no\y
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry I'm new to regex, why would changing the order have any effect? I tried replacing it with the regex "(?i)^(.*?)\b no\b" and it works, but the result is not what it expected, it doesn't match

Comment: Because `(?i)` must be at the _beginning_ of the regular expression in PostgreSQL, as the documentation states. If you put it into the middle, PostgreSQL doesn't like it. I also overlooked another issue; I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Amadan
what case-insensitivity means differs between Python and PostgreSQL, additionally the definition of word boundaries will differ.